# How to transform table from one row per ID to one row per ID per column?

Tags: r, row, transform, multiple-columns

I have the following table:

Table <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2),A=c("TRUE","FALSE"), B=c("1","2"))

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "TRUE" | "1" |
| 2 | "FALSE" | "2" |

I want to transform it into the following table:

Table_transformed <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,1,2),COLUMN=c("A","A","B","B"), VALUE=c("TRUE","FALSE","1","2"))

| ID | COLUMN | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | "TRUE" |
| 2 | A | "FALSE" |
| 1 | B | "1" |
| 2 | B | "2" |

How to do this?

I have not found a way to do this yet without using non-generalized for-loops etc.

Answer (score 0):

A tidyverse solution:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2),A=c("TRUE","FALSE"), B=c("1","2"))

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df1 |> 
pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = "Column", values_to = "VALUE") |> 
arrange(Column)  

#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>      ID Column VALUE
#>   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>
#> 1     1 A      TRUE 
#> 2     2 A      FALSE
#> 3     1 B      1    
#> 4     2 B      2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>